# How can I create text style like google snapseed

Tags: android, android-studio

How can I create text style like google snapseed.

Like this 
[google snapseed text style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2HJd.png)

Comment: I found this https://www.quora.com/Which-fonts-are-used-in-Googles-Snapseed-app which lists the font family used in google snapseed. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, but that is not useful :)

Answer (score 0):

For Achieving this style you need to use font family used by the app you are following and also use text styles like bold, italic etc. By using this methodology you can easily achieve your goal.